# Radio buttons in a Semantic UI React table retain checked attribute after selecting another radio button in the same row?

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

My radio buttons have the same name so the behavior I would expect is to:

- select a radio button
- see that it has the `checked` attribute
- select a different radio button in the same row, and then
- see that it has the `checked` attribute while the first one no longer does.

Instead:

- I click a radio button
- see that it is `checked`
- click a different one, and
- the UI shows that the first one is no longer checked but it retains the `checked` attribute when I inspect the source.

Why are these radio buttons not fully interacting with each other?

```
                  <Form onSubmit={(e) => { handleAnswerFormSubmit(e) }}>
                    <Table celled>
                      <Table.Body>
                        <Table.Row>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            airplane
                          </Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <Radio name="airplane" value="1" />
                          </Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <Radio name="airplane" value="2" />
                          </Table.Cell>
                          <Table.Cell>
                            <Radio name="airplane" value="3" />
                          </Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                      </Table.Body>
                    </Table>
                    <Form.Button>Continue</Form.Button>
                  </Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Radio group`. The following example, also available on [Semantic UI React Docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/radio/#types-radio-group) will help you. Here goes the code:

```
export default class RadioExampleRadioGroup extends Component {
  state = {}
  handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })

  render() {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Form.Field>
          Selected value: <b>{this.state.value}</b>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label='Choose this'
            name='radioGroup'
            value='this'
            checked={this.state.value === 'this'}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Radio
            label='Or that'
            name='radioGroup'
            value='that'
            checked={this.state.value === 'that'}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```